# Prove that, any continuous and periodic function on $\Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, periodic-functions

There is a hint in my book to solve the problem. It goes as follows-

> Suppose, $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and has the period
>   $p\in\Bbb{R}$. Hence, $f(x+np)=f(x)\forall x\in\Bbb{R}, \: \forall
>  n\in\Bbb{Z} $
>  Thus, $f$ is continuous on $[0,p]\implies f$ is
>   uniformly continuous on $[0,p]$.
>  Choose $\varepsilon>0$, then
>   $\exists \delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta,\:x,y\in[0,p]$ we have
>   $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$
>  Now, take any two $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ with
>   $|x-y|<\delta$. **Now, we can find an integer $j$ such that $x+jp,\:
> > y+jp \in[0,p]$. Then $|x-y|<\delta\implies|(x+jp)-(y+jp)|<\delta$**,
>   hence from the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[0,p]$ we have
>   $|f(x+jp)-f(y+jp)|<\varepsilon\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$
>   Therefore, $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ with
>   $|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ and this is true for any
>   arbitrarily chosen $\varepsilon>0$.

Now, **my question is**:: How for $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ we can have **SAME** $j\in\Bbb{Z}$ for which both of $(x+jp),\:(y+jp)\in [0,p]$. Although I can establish that we can find $n, m\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $(x+np),\:(y+mp)\in [0,p]$(beacuse $x,y\in\Bbb{R}\implies\exists n_1,m_1\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $(n_1-1)p\le x\le {n_1}p,\:(m_1-1)p\le y\le {m_1}p\implies 0\le x-(n_1 -1)p\le p, \: 0\le y-(m_1 -1)p\le p$, now just fix $(n_1 -1)=n,\: (m_1 -1)=m$). **BUT HOW THESE $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$ CAN BE SAME?**
Can anybody clear up my confusion?
Thank for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. Prove instead the uniform continuity on $[0,2p]$. Now, in the definition of uniform continuity, the $\delta$ can always be chosen to be $<p$. This is because if a $\delta$ works for a given $\epsilon$, then any smaller positive $\delta$ also works. When $\delta <p$, then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that there is single $j$ such that $x+jp,y+jp\in [0,2p]$. You can see why I took an interval the size of double the period. The thing is that even if $x$ and $y$ are very close, the $x$ can be very close to $p$ from below, and then the $y$ fall above $p$.

Comment: @fishroe, can please explain how does the single $j$ come?

Comment: @fishroe No matter how small $\delta$ we choose, take $x \in \left\langle 2p -\frac\delta2, 2p\right\rangle$ and $y \in \left\langle 2p, 2p +\frac\delta2\right\rangle$. We have $|x-y| < \delta$ but $x+jp, y+jp$ cannot both be in $[0,2p]$ for any $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid You are confused. If $x,y$ are as in your example, and $\delta <p$, then take $j'= j-1$ and $x$ is going to be in $[0,p]$ and $y$ in $[p,2p]$.

Comment: @fishroe, one thing I should mention- why you are considering $\delta < p$? here you are working with the interval $[0,2p]$ instead of $[0,p]$ so there may be a $\varepsilon >0$ for which $p<\delta <2p$

Comment: @BiswarupSaha You need to understand the definition of uniform continuity: "For all $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$" This means the existence of a function $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ with those properties. But the thing is that if $\delta(\epsilon)$, makes the proposition true, then $\delta'(\epsilon)=\min(\delta(\epsilon),p)$ also makes the proposition true. That is why $\delta$ can be assumed, to not only satisfy the definition of uniform continuity, but also to be $<p$.

Comment: @fishroe, ok now I understand, thanks for assistance